# What occupies the space of a molecule in a gas which moves away due to kinetic energy?

Tags: ideal-gas

The gas state means it has lot of kinetic energy and the momentum of molecules transfer the energy on The container wall and is pressure.but during displacement of each molecule, what occupies it's previous position?
Will it be occupied by another molecule?

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, I am sure that another molecule of the gas will occupy the same position. However, when one molecule moves away from somewhere, nothing need fill the empty space behind it. A vacuum does not suck molecules into it, molecules will only move to fill an empty space because the net pressure from collisions with other molecules pushes them into it.

Comment: Indeed, and in fact it would be impossible for the gas molecules to fill up all the empty space anyways! Consider 1 mol of, say, Helium gas, which occupies 22.4 L at STP. The He molecule has a volume of about 7.02x10^-29 L; so all of the molecules combined take up only about 4.23x10^-5 L. Therefore, about 99.9998% of the 22.4L container is empty space!